# Why are subviews of an NSView not sent a release message when a Cocoa application terminates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsview

**The short version:**

1. Why are the subviews of NSView objects not sent a `release` message when a Cocoa application terminates?

   Is there a way to override this behaviour?

**An example:**
The `MyView` class shown below is nothing more than an `NSView` subclass that reports to the console when it is created and destroyed. I have tested it out and found it to work properly. However, when I use it as shown in the next code snippet from my application delegate, I see something unexpected (see sample output).

```
// MyView:

@interface MyView : NSView { }
@end

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) == nil) { return nil; }
    NSLog(@"init %@", self);
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc %@", self);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

```
// Application delegate:

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"begin");

    parentView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    MyView * myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 80, 80)];
    [parentView addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];

    NSLog(@"run");
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"quit");
    [parentView release];
    NSLog(@"end.");
}
```

This application produces the following output:

> begin
>   init `<`MyView: 0x10013f840`>`
>   init `<`MyView: 0x10261b620`>`
>   run
>   quit
>   dealloc `<`MyView: 0x10013f840`>`
>   end.

**The problem:**
I can clearly see that the first view object is being released when the application quits, and I'm certain (tested and verified) that `NSView` objects automatically release their subviews when they themselves are released. However, it appears that during application termination those subviews are not being released.

**The long version: (AKA why on earth would anyone care? :)**
Let me start by saying that I am familiar with the way memory is freed by a running application when it quits. I know that my subviews will be properly disposed of, even if they are never sent a `release` message, so I'm not worried about this being a leak. In fact, I'm pretty sure (but not 100% certain) that the answer to my question #1 is: "Because releasing subviews is unnecessary when the application is about to terminate."

I use some simple hand-rolled code to do memory tracking while my application is running in debug mode. I make a calls to a `Trace_Init()` and `Trace_Dealloc()` method in the `init` and `dealloc` methods of all of my custom classes, and I use the `atexit()` function to report any unreleased objects after the Cocoa portion of my application has finished. I find this to be much simpler than running Apple's memory leak performance tool on a regular basis. If I cause a memory leak while running, I'll know about it as soon as my application quits.

However, the lack of a `dealloc` call during termination means that any of my custom `NSView` subclasses that are used as subviews show up as memory leaks when I quit the application. Thus the reason for my question #2. I would like to have Cocoa release everything during termination so that my memory tracking is able to wrap up properly. Naturally, I would only override the default behaviour in debug mode. My released app has none of the memory tracking code enabled, and should be able to quit itself as efficiently as normal.

**That's it!** (phew) If you made it this far, thank you for taking the time to read it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was to create and release my own `NSAutoreleasePool` within the `applicationWillTerminate:` method.

**Details:**
Deep in the bowels of `NSView`'s `dealloc` method, all kinds of things are done to remove the view and all of its subviews from the responder chain, set up the next key view, send delegate messages, etc. Somewhere in this code, each subview is sent a `retain` message, and later sent an `autorelease` message. (Actually, each subview is retained and autoreleased twice - see details below). This is normal, but here's the kicker: When the subviews are sent an `autorelease` message, they get added to whatever `NSAutoreleasePool` happens to be active at that point in time, and they are kept around until that particular pool goes out of scope. In the case of application termination, the pool they get added to is the one created automatically during each iteration of the application's main event loop, *and this pool is never sent a* `release` *message because the application is about to quit!*

**Experimental results:**
I added a bunch of logging messages to the `init`, `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` methods for `MyView`, which all have code similar to this:

```
NSLog(@"[%@ retain]:  count = %d", [self name], [self retainCount]+1);
return [super retain];
```

I also logged `{` `}` around the code for `dealloc` so I could see when the magic happens.

Using these logging messages, here is what happens to my `NSView` obejcts:

```
begin  
[parent init]:        count = 1
[subview init]:        count = 1
[subview retain]:      count = 2
[subview release]:     count = 1
run
quit
[parent release]:     count = 0
[parent dealloc]
{
    [subview retain]:      count = 2
    [subview autorelease]: count = 2
    [subview retain]:      count = 3
    [subview autorelease]: count = 3
    [subview release]:     count = 2
}
end.
```

Now, when I use the following code in `applicationWillTerminate:`

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"quit");
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [parentView release];
    [pool release];
    NSLog(@"end.");
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
begin  
[parent init]:        count = 1
[subview init]:        count = 1
[subview retain]:      count = 2
[subview release]:     count = 1
run
quit
[parent release]:     count = 0
[parent dealloc]
{
    [subview retain]:      count = 2
    [subview autorelease]: count = 2
    [subview retain]:      count = 3
    [subview autorelease]: count = 3
    [subview release]:     count = 2
}
[subview release]:     count = 1
[subview release]:     count = 0
[subview dealloc]
{
}
end.
```

And you can clearly see the two `release` messages sent to the subview by the `NSAutoreleasePool` as it drains.

**References:**
[NSView.m](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/gui/trunk/Source/NSView.m?rev=28201&view=markup) from GNUStep
[Autorelease Pools](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) from Apple's developer documentation

Answer (score 3):

It's not just views. It's everything. I don't think even the NSApplication object releases itself.

> In fact, I'm pretty sure (but not 100% certain) that the answer to my question #1 is: "Because releasing subviews is unnecessary when the application is about to terminate."

I believe so as well.

If you want to your custom object graph released at quit, have your app delegate own it, and release your other top-level objects in applicationWillTerminate:. As long as you're managing all your ownerships correctly and you release every single top-level custom object from that method, all your custom objects, including views, will die.

Note: I have not tried mixing this with Core Data. It may or may not be possible to do this to your managed objects. I don't have any first-hand experience with that.

Comment: Re: "If you want to your custom object graph released at quit, have your app delegate own it...": That's what I thought, too, but take a look at the example I gave. parentView is owned by the app delegate, and it is released in applicationWillTerminate, but its subview is never released.

Comment: Logic would seem to indicate that something else must have a retain on the view.

Comment: @Chuck: You're right. It was the global NSAutoreleasePool that still held ownership of the subview after it had been autoreleased. I posted an answer with all of the dirty details.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: You were right about the termination behaviour, and I upvoted this answer accordingly. I figured out the rest of it after some digging. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you presented you are adding the subview to an ivar called 'view'. Is that what you really did or is it just from copying code to the question?

I ask this because if I create an IBOutlet to the main window's content view and run your code it does what you say. But if I add the myView local var to parentView then it does deallocate:

```
begin
init <MyView: 0x174460>
init <MyView: 0x174770>
run
quit
dealloc <MyView: 0x174460>
end
dealloc <MyView: 0x174770>
```

In addition it appears that sub views get autoreleased (adding a log message to autorelease proves it).

Comment: Good catch. I renamed the variable `parentView` when posting the question in order to make it easier to discuss. I have now fixed it in the question.

Comment: With that change the program will not give the output you showed. There must be something else you are doing and did not show that is, as Chuck pointed out, retaining the subview.

Comment: +1: I managed to figure out what was going in, but thank you for taking the time to try out the code. You're absolutely right about the autorelease messages being sent to the subviews, and in the end it was the global autorelease pool that wasn't being drained.

Comment: Re: "With that change the program will not give the output you showed." On my machine, it certainly does, and that is the exact code I am using to test. parentView is an ivar of my application delegate, and I do not make it an IBOutlet. myView is not an ivar, and it exists (as a variable) only within applicationDidFinishLaunching. Beyond that, only parentView owns it. Could this behaviour be something new in Xcode version 3.2?